# RealmResults to RecyclerView

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-recyclerview, realm

I wanted to ask if it is safe to pass RealmResults to RecyclerView Adapter. Like this:

```
    public MyAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<SomeStuff> stuff){
    this.stuff = stuff
}

//Somewhere later in the adapter

    @Override
    public SomeStuff getItem(int position) {
        return stuff.get(position);
    }
```

And by "safe" I actually mean memory leaks. Can this kind of reference potentially lead to a memory leak? Or it is fine as don't forget to close Realm in my fragment? Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188310/2413303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good way to do it.
Check this example
http://gradlewhy.ghost.io/realm-results-with-recyclerview/

As you can see in the example they are passing the same RealResult by the constructor, i have 4 apps using Realm with RecyclerView.
I have been working for months with Realm and i have not had problems,
however you have to know Realm is growing up everyday and it is still a beta 0.83.0 and maybe you can find some leaks.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: By the way, do you have experience using Realm with ViewPager, where each fragment inside VP uses Realm? Is it still okay to open/close Realm in onCreate()/onDestroy() of a fragment?

Comment: Well,  usually i declare  private Realm realm;
then onCreate() realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); and onDestroy don't remember to close Realm when done.  as Example says. Have you downloaded the examples? There are 7 examples and you can get good references.