# Realm Java: RealmChange Listener + notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't Update UI when new Item Added

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using Realm Java ORM for my android app. My main problem is that the recycler view doesn't show new item when added from some other realm instance (for ex: new record added from a Service).

Suppose my recycler view with RealmRecylerViewAdapter is laid out and visible in an activity. My data is stored in realm table (say A) and auto refresh is enabled.

I have set realm change listener like this(in the same activity as recycler view):

```
 realm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() {
            if(mAdapter!=null){
                mAdapter.getRealmAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now when I add new row for table A, Realm Change listener should auto update recycler view, except that the new item doesn't show up.

Alternative is to again set adapter with fresh realm query. Problem with that is that it resets the Recycler view, and user seeing the list is scrolled to top.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From a quick glance it should work. Have you verified that the `RealmChangeListener` is triggered? That should tell if you if the problem is with Realm or how the RecyclerView invalidate the data set.

Comment: Why does your RecyclerView even **have** a RealmAdapter? Why do you have **two** adapters? If you want an auto-updating RecyclerView adapter, you should use the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31188310/2413303